# GraphQL Apollo remove dangling references

Tags: graphql, apollo

Since Apollo client 3.0 a normalised object can be deleted from the cache using `cache.evict`, like so:

```js
{
  update: (cache, { data: updateData }) => {
    if (isNil(updateData)) return

    const { id } = updateData.removeSomething
    cache.evict({ id: `Something:${id}` })
    cache.gc()
  }
}
```

However, deleting it in this manner still seems to leave dangling pointers to the object in lists it appeared in. Appearing like so in the cache:

```
[{__ref: "Something:9180d367-b018-46c1-b9cf-049258408fd8"}]
```

How can these references to the object be removed without knowing the parent ID?

Edit:
[This pull request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/6412) answers it to a degree, but doesn't find anything with the child ID.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you evict an object (such as `Something:${id}`), references to it in the cache *are not removed*. The references become [dangling references](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/garbage-collection/#dangling-references), means they point to a nonexistent object. These references remain in case the object is subsequently restored.

Summary, even though the cached list's contents include the dangling reference, query results for that list shouldn't